# Effects of C# async

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am learning about C# async, and am trying to understand exactly what the effects of making a method async are.

If I have the following method (not async):

```
public bool method()
{
     int a = 2 + 1;      //line 1
     string b = "test";  //line 2
     double c = 2.14;    //line 3
     return true;        //line 4
}
```

In the above method, the compiler will execute each line in order, for example, first it will execute line 1, then line 2 etc

My question relates to the effects on the order of execution that adding in async, as below, will have.

```
public async Task<bool> method()
{
     int a = 2 + 1;      //line 1
     string b = "test";  //line 2
     double c = 2.14;    //line 3
     return true;        //line 4
}
```

Is it the case that adding in async will cause  the compiler to now execute lines 1, 2, 3 and 4 concurrently?

And if so, if I do the following:

```
public async Task<bool> method()
{
     int a = await addNumbers(2, 1);      //line 1
     string b = "test";                   //line 2
     double c = 2.14;                     //line 3
     return true;                         //line 4
}

public async Task<int> addNumbers(int a, int b)
{         
     return a + b;
}
```

Then it seems to me that the compiler will execute line 1, and once it has completed line 1, it will then complete lines 2, 3 and 4 concurrently. Is this correct?

and finally, if the above is also correct, in this situation

```
public async Task<bool> method()
{
     int a = 2 + 1;                       //line 1
     string b = "test";                   //line 2
     double c = await getDouble();        //line 3
     double d = await getDouble();        //line 4
     int e = 2 + 1;                       //line 5
     int f = 2 + 1;                       //line 6
     return true;                         //line 7
}

public async Task<double> getDouble()
{         
     return 2.14;
}
```

It seems to me that the compiler will execute lines 1 and 2 concurrently, then once that is complete it will execute line 3, then once that is complete it will execute line 4, then once line 4 is complete it will execute lines 5 and 6 concurrently?

I have not been able to find anything which details this clearly for me, so if anyone has any good article which explain this clearly that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time"? While it may appear like that because of the speed and multiple cores or threads, a CPU can essentially only do one thing at a time. With or without async, code is still executed sequentially.

Comment: Async is not (usually) about multithreading. You're on the wrong path. Also, __read the warnings__  when you compile this.

Comment: @CodeCaster do you mean that even though I declare async, the code is still always executed on the same thread, and it does not cause a method to run concurrently?

Comment: For the second code block, you're asking _"execute lines 1, 2, 3 and 4 all at the same time?"_. No, it won't spawn a thread per line of code. Again, explain very explicitly what you mean by "at the same time".

Comment: I suggest to google a little bit, there are a lot of good articles about `async/await` and what the compiler does about that on the web. The way it stands, this question is much too broad for a Q&A site like SO, as your (multiple) questions show that one would have to explain the whole concept of `async/await` to answer this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`async` does not "parallelize" the method. That method still uses the regular flow.

Instead `async` enables the `await` keyword. Using `await` can postpone the execution of the method until the awaited method is done. 
The advantage is that in the meantime other code can run - await does not block the thread.

**EDIT**
You would use `await` mainly on IO-bound calls, such as to a database or webservice (and on any method that calls an async method). While "that other system" is processing your request, your own application doesn't need to block but can process other code while you "await" the results. When that other system returns results, your method continues processing.